# Access exception.class.name in spring:message tag when using SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

Tags: spring, servlets, exception, jstl

In several previous projects (all pre-Spring 3.0), I had a single error handling jsp file (usually "message.jsp") that had a line similar to the following:

```
<spring:message code="exceptions.${exception.class.name}" text="${exception.message}"/>
```

This allowed me to map exceptions to this page and resolve certain localized error messages based on the exception type by defining a derivative of the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver:

```
<bean id="exceptionMapping" class="mycode.ui.resolvers.MyExceptionResolver">
  <property name="exceptionMappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="java.lang.Exception">message</prop>
      <prop key="javax.servlet.ServletException">message</prop>
      <prop key="MyCustomException">message</prop>
      <prop key="ApplicationAuthorizationException">login</prop>
      <prop key="NotLoggedInException">login</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This worked flawlessly until I tried upgrading to Spring 3 and Tomcat 7. Now, when I use this code, I get the following error:

```
"${exception.class.name}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: The identifier [class] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification
```

Any idea what's changed or how to access the class name of the exception (part of the model returned by Spring to the mapped error page)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The EL implementation in Tomcat 7 has indeed been changed to disallow Java keyword literals such as `class`, `new`, `static` etcetera as EL properties.

The only solution as far is to access them using the brace notation instead:

```
${exception['class'].name}
```

See also [Tomcat issue 50147](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50147).

Comment: I think I've figured out that just using "exception" does the same thing.  Thank you!

Comment: To find occurrences you can use this RegEx: (\$\{)(.*?)(?<!\[(?:"|'))\.(abstract|assert|boolean|break|byte|case|catch|char|class|const|continue|default|do|double|else|enum|extends|final|finally|float|for|goto|if|implements|import|instanceof|int|interface|long|native|new|package|private|protected|public|return|short|static|strictfp|super|switch|synchronized|this|throw|throws|transient|try|void|volatile|while)\b(?!(?:"|')\])(.*?)(\})